# JavaScript Dates, Sunday

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function which determines next for date for the week day. It works for all days, except Sunday.

```
For Sunday:
Sun May 25 2014
Sun Jun 08 2014
Sun Jun 22 2014

For Saturday:
Sat May 24 2014
Sat May 31 2014
Sat Jun 07 2014
Sat Jun 14 2014
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MfTe4/)!

```
function getDatesByweekDay(weekday){
     var startdate = new Date();
     var date2 = new Date();
     lastday = new Date(date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 28 + weekday - date2.getDay()));       
     var dates = Array();
     var x = 0;
     do {
         startdate = new Date(startdate.setDate(startdate.getDate() + 7 + weekday - startdate.getDay()));
          console.log(startdate);
          var date = new Date();
          var curr_date = startdate.getDate();
          var curr_month = startdate.getMonth() + 1;
          var curr_year = startdate.getFullYear();

          var formattedDate = curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date;

          dates[x] = formattedDate;
          x++;
      } while(lastday > startdate);

      return dates;     
  }

getDatesByweekDay(6);
```

Comment: If you look at the fiddle, it's skipping some Sundays

Comment: for sunday return only 3 dates and dates are not in order

Comment: Use 0 instead of 7 for Sunday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because you're passing in the 8th day of a 7-day week. If you pass in a number from 14-20, it'll skip two weeks instead of one week between returned dates.

The problem has to do with the first line of your `do...while`:

```
startdate = new Date(startdate.setDate(startdate.getDate() + 7 + weekday - startdate.getDay()));
```

You're adding 7 to advance it 1 week, plus the weekday, minus the day of the week of the startdate. If your `weekday` variable is 1 week or more, it's going to advance it more than one week. Since it should be a number from 0 to 6, and you're passing in 7, you're experiencing this bug.

You can fix it a few different ways, but just normalizing the input `weekday` to a number from 0-6 will solve it. Add `weekday = weekday % 7;` near the beginning of your function.

Comment: If you use the `weekday = weekday % 7` solution, it will even work for negative numbers!

Comment: thank you for full answer. 
I have one more question.
for example for saterday it start from 24 May. I want to start from 17. Is there in js some function or something to fix it? or I must write some If ELSE?

Comment: I reworked your function so it will show the next 4, with today included. jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qc6K8/2/

Answer (score 2):

when you call

```
getDatesByweekDay(0);
```

it seems to return the right information you're looking at.